# Block youtube via hosts file

Tags: linux, networking, youtube, blocking, hosts

I would like to block some distracting websites from my computer.

I figured the `/etc/hosts` file would be the right place to do so, because it will apply to all browsers and clients.
So this is what my file looks like:

```
0.0.0.0   reddit.com
::0       reddit.com

0.0.0.0   colonist.io
::0       colonist.io

0.0.0.0   youtube.com
::0       youtube.com

0.0.0.0   youtube.de
::0       youtube.de
```

Visiting `colonist.io` and `reddit.com` is (as expected) impossible now (firefox reports "Unable to connect").

But somehow it doesn't work for youtube. I can visit youtube.com just fine. I don't know why that is and would like to learn how to fix it.

Alternatively I would also accept other ways to block   sites system-wide on linux.

Comment: Using the hosts file is an absolutely horrible way to block a website. My suggestion use something like OpenDNS to accomplish what you want, and even better solution, use a firewall or proxy so you can block it on all devices regardless of their OS

Comment: @Ramhound As far as I know, normal firewalling doesn't deal with domain names. And I want to block these sites from my computer only, others in the network should be free to do what they want. And a proxy seems a bit like overkill to me, although I might not be thinking of the same setup like you are. Could you get into more detail about the firewall idea? I am on nixos, but generic firewall advice will probably do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube uses multiple domains which redirect to each other. For example, youtube.com will usually redirect to [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com).

I don’t know exactly why the dns blocking youtube.com doesn’t block a redirect, but I did this myself a while ago and adding other sites to the blocklist helped.

So add the following domains to your blocklist:
[www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)
m.youtube.com
youtu.be

Hope I was able to help!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding a new entry with `www` did the trick. I thought that `www.youtube.com` should be part of `youtube.com` and would be part of the same lookup. But I guess I was wrong. Networking is hard. Thank you.

Comment: @Kaligule I have no clue why blocking youtube.com doesn’t prevent redirection, it could be that the browser automatically changes it. Confusing! I had the exact same issue trying to do a similar thing but with a DNS I wrote myself, thus I had more logs available. I was confused, but im glad I could help.